# How can I get the output of this function to print onto different lines in R?

Tags: r, function

So, I am writing a function that, among many other things, is supposed to keep only the first sentence from each paragraph of a text and preserve the paragraph structure (i.e. each sentence is in its own line). Here is the code that I have so far:

```
text_shortener <- function(input_text) {
   lapply(input_text, function(x)str_split(x, "\\.", simplify = T)[1])
   first.sentences <- unlist(lapply(input_text, function(x)str_split(x, "\\.", simplify = T)[1]))
   no.spaces <- gsub(pattern = "(?<=[\\s])\\s*|^\\s+|\\s+$", replacement = "", x = first.sentences, perl = TRUE)
   stopwords <- c("the", "really", "truly", "very", "The", "Really", "Truly", "Very")
   x <- unlist(strsplit(no.spaces, " "))
   no.stopwords <- paste(x[!x %in% stopwords], collapse = " ")
   final.text <- gsub(pattern = "(?<=\\w{5})\\w+", replacement = ".", x = no.stopwords, perl=TRUE)
   return(final.text)
 }
```

All of the functions are working as they should, but the one part I can't figure out is how to get the output to print onto separate lines. When I run the function with a vector of text (I was using some text from Moby Dick as a test), this is what I get:

```
> text_shortener(Moby_Dick)
[1] "Call me Ishma. It is a way I have of drivi. off splee., and regul. circu. This is my subst. for pisto. and ball"
```

What I want is for the output of this function to look like this:

```
[1] "Call me Ishma."
[2] "It is a way I have of drivi. off splee., and regul. circu."
[3] "This is my subst. for pisto. and ball"
```

I am relatively new to R and this giving me a real headache, so any help would be much appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your output, it seems like splitting on a period followed by a capital letter if what you need.

You could accomplish that with `strsplit()` and split the string up like so:

```
strsplit("Call me Ishma. It is drivi. off splee., and regul. circu. This is my subst. for pisto.","\\. (?=[A-Z])", perl=T)
```

That finds instances where a period is followed by a space and a capital letter and splits the character up there.

Edit: You could add it to the end of your function like so:

```
text_shortener <- function(input_text) {
  lapply(input_text, function(x)str_split(x, "\\.", simplify = T)[1])
  first.sentences <- unlist(lapply(input_text, function(x)str_split(x, "\\.", simplify = T)[1]))
  no.spaces <- gsub(pattern = "(?<=[\\s])\\s*|^\\s+|\\s+$", replacement = "", x = first.sentences, perl = TRUE)
  stopwords <- c("the", "really", "truly", "very", "The", "Really", "Truly", "Very")
  x <- unlist(strsplit(no.spaces, " "))
  no.stopwords <- paste(x[!x %in% stopwords], collapse = " ")
  trim.text <- gsub(pattern = "(?<=\\w{5})\\w+", replacement = ".", x = no.stopwords, perl=TRUE)
  final.text <- strsplit(trim.text, "\\. (?=[A-Z])", perl=T)
  return(final.text)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Is there a way to incorporate this into the body of the function so that the output is already formatted this way?

Comment: @MeganDougherty sure thing - I edited my answer to include a version of your function with the additional code added. It sounds like this answers your question - if so, I would appreciate if you accepted my answer by click on the check mark next to it. Thanks!

Comment: If I answered your question, please go ahead and click the check mark next to my answer :) if not, feel free to let me know.